# Why my log in system using CI sessions doesn't allow me retrieve any data that i did store in database

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, session, mysqli

I have a table with the following columns:

```
session_id       varchar(40)    No      0        
ip_address       varchar(16)    No      0        
user_agent       varchar(50)    No           
last_activity    int(10)        No      0        
user_data        text           No
```

I tried to get the sessions i created but it doesnt return any value.
I also tried to create them as database fields, and that was wrong too.
I also tried to save them in cookies, instead of DB, still did not work.

this is my PHP script:

```
$user_data = array(
                'id' => $row->id,
                'is_logged' => TRUE
            );
$this->session->set_userdata($user_data);
```

I tried retrieving it by using this :

```
$this->session->userdata('is_logged');/is_logged is an example
```

Note:
I'm new to Codeigniter.

Answer (score 2):

The CI Session Class will allow you to store sessions in the database (note that this doesn't negate the use of cookies, just adds an extra layer of persistence for security in case you need to validate a session ID). Here is the sql statement to create the session table.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `ci_sessions` (
    session_id varchar(40) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    ip_address varchar(16) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    user_agent varchar(120) NOT NULL,
    last_activity int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    user_data text NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (session_id),
    KEY `last_activity_idx` (`last_activity`)
);
```

Then, you need to tell CI to use the database for session data:

```
// in /application/config.php
$config['sess_use_database'] = TRUE;

// and what the name of the db table is
$config['sess_table_name'] = 'ci_sessions';
```

Then, when you log in your user, you'd add details to their session data:

```
$this->session->set_userdata('id', $user_id);
$this->session->set_userdata('username', $username);
$this->session->set_userdata('email', $email);
$this->session->set_userdata('isLogged', TRUE);
```

And this is what you'd use to see if someone has access to a page or resource.

```
if ($this->session->userdata('isLogged') === TRUE)
{
    // show page
}
else
{
    // show access error
}
```

Comment: I followed you steps carefully, but still the same result `is_logged` and `id` are `NULL`.

Comment: I edit my question, I tried adding `is_logged` and `id` as database fields, and that was wrong. After that i tried using them as session variables, and still did not work, whenever i try to retrieve them i get nothing.

Comment: Pro answer swatkins!! Thanks!!! You've helped me out! Your answer should be green!